# Datetime picker for Reactive forms using Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6, datetimepicker, angular-reactive-forms

Where can i find, Date and Time picker in angular6 using reactive forms? I have tried many examples found in various blogs and that all tend to be of Template Driven forms, I want a DateTime control for reactive forms because i have a form developed using Reactive form approach, i have tried all this links and found none to be of Reactive Form approach

1. [link1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime)
2. [link2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker)
3. [link3](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/)

Comment: link 3 NgPickDateTime provided the reactive approach also please check it once it's documentation

Comment: Quite late to the party, but I am in the process of implementing this. This is the only one I found that I have had any luck with sadly. https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-material-109-datepicker-timepicker-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

You can use mydatepicker

Step 1 : npm command : npm install mydatepicker --save

Step 2 : Import in app.module.ts

import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';

Step 3:  select the options required in the component

import { IMyDpOptions } from "mydatepicker";

myDPOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
              dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
              openSelectorTopOfInput: true
            }

Step 4 : use the below tag in html template

```
      <my-date-picker  name = "setName" 
      [options]="myDPOptions" [(ngModel)]="setName">
      </my-date-picker>
```

Comment: i am searching for date&time picker not the date picker

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the Ng Bootstrap Datepicker for that purpose. They have included a few [samples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) on how to use it.

The installation is simple:

```
npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

On your component that requires the datepicker, you can simply import the required DatePicker module (instead of the entire ng boostrap library)

sample.module.ts

```
import { NgbDatepickerModule, NgbTimepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
.
.

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgbDatepickerModule,
    NgbTimepickerModule
     .
     .
  ],
  .
  .
}]
```

On your component.html, you can supply the formControlName to the your DatePicker and TimePicker inputs:

```
<input class="form-control" ngbDatepicker (click)="datePicker.toggle()" #datePicker="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="startDate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
<ngb-timepicker formControlName="startTime" meridian="meridian"></ngb-timepicker>
```

And on your component.ts,

```
sampleForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  startDate: [null, Validators.required],
  startTIme: [null, Validators.required],

  // the other form controls
});
```

I have implmented both Time and Date Picker components on this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdxxwm?file=app/app.module.ts) .

Check out the full [API documentation for DatePicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api) and [TimePicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/api) for more details and customisation options.

Comment: i am searching for date&time picker not the date picker, i dont find a dateTime picker in the example which u have provided

Comment: @LijinDurairaj Sorry, I forgot to include the TimePicker. I have updated my answer, and included a demo on how to use them with reactive forms